# Need description of pointer and dereference operators in C

Tags: c

What I'm trying to understand is the following :

1st question - Let's say that we declared a variable char *mystring . What's the difference between *mystring and &mystring and mystring ?

2nd Question -

```
char* str = "Hello!";
MessageBox(NULL,str,str,NULL);
```

How can we interprate str used as an argument in this function : is it an address of the pointer or address of the string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After these lines:

```
int num;
int *pNum = &num;
```

- `pNum` is value of pointer, which is an address of `num`
- `*pNum` is dereferenced pointer, referring to `num` directly, i.e. `*pNum = 3;` assigns `3` to `num`
- `&pNum` can be used to retrieve an address of the pointer itself

Now let's say you have function taking argument of type `const char*`, let's say [`strlen`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strlen):

```
char* str = "Hello!";
int len = strlen(str);
```

creates a pointer to `char` named `str` that points to the memory (which is read-only by the way) where character `'H'` is stored. `strlen(str)` passes an address of this character to `strlen` function that starts counting letters that follow after `'H'` untill it reaches `'\0'` (null-terminating character).

Comment: *str = dereferenced pointer : points to the first character ...
&str == the address of the pointer ...
str == the address of the string ... Is that it ?

Comment: @user2836131: Yes, just note that type of `*str` will be `char`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure you realize that books (or at least chapters) have been written on this subject.  It would probably help you to read any of them, because understanding that will take more explanation than you can usually get in one question.

Let's see if I can help you by showing you what the memory could look like inside your program:

```
0xBB000000  0xBB000001  0xBB000002  0xBB000003
   'H'          'e'         'l'         'l'

0xBB000004  0xBB000005  0xBB000006  0xBB000007
   'o'          '!'        '\0'         240

0x74320000  0x74320001  0x74320002  0x74320003
   0xBB        0x00        0x00        0x00
```

Obviously, things can be anywhere in memory, but this shows the basic idea.  Your string is stored somewhere, I've placed it at 0xBB000000, and it will take up contiguous memory, and be terminated with a \0.  (Address 0xBB000007 is just there for completeness, and has some other value that could be anything.)  I've placed the variable `str` somewhere else in memory (since string constants and stack variables are usually placed in different spots).  So the value of `str` takes up 4 bytes, and I started it in 0x74320000.  If you put the 4 bytes from there together, you'll have the 0xBB000000, which is the address of your actual string.  (Note, your computer may actually represent this number in a different order, but I'm assuming big-endian for simplicity.)

char * str = "Hello!" tells the compiler to make a pointer to a character, and call that `str`, and have it point to the string "Hello!".  So, str is a variable, and it stores a pointer.

If you print out the value of str in this example, in this case it will return `(char *)0xBB000000`.

If you look at *str, that means it takes its value `(char *)0xBB000000` and dereferences it.  That is, it returns whatever character is stored in that pointer.  In this case, that's 'H'.

If you look at &str, that's actually the address of the variable.  In this case, that would return the `(void *) 0x74320000`.

Just to make it more confusing, if you look at `str[0]`, that's the same as `*str` (while `str[1]` is the same as `*(str + 1)` and will return 'e').  If you look at `&str[2]`, that's taking the address of `str[2]`, which is the address that holds the first letter 'l', 0xBB000002.

Of the two options you asked in part2, the "address of the string" is the better answer, though what you're really doing is passing in the char * to the string.  Inside the function, that parameter is actually a copy of the value, and not the original value.  I.e., inside MessageBox, &parameter2 and &parameter3 will **not** return 0x74320000, but parameter2 and parameter3 will each hold the value 0xBB000000 in it.

Answer (score 0):

> 1st question - Let's say that we declared a variable char *mystring . What's the difference between *mystring and &mystring and mystring ?

I am assuming
    char *mystring = "Hello!";

`*mystring` gives you first `cahr` of the string `Hello!`, i.e, `H`.
`&mystrimg` is the address of pointer `mystring`
`mystring` is a pointer to the first element of the string `Hello!`

> How can we interprate str used as an argument in this function : is it an address of the pointer or address of the string?

`str` is not the address of pointer but it will decays to a pointer to the first element of the given string on passing it to the function `MessageBox`.

Answer (score 0):

*mystring is dereference of character pointer means its is first character in string

mystring is address of first character

&mystring is address of string.